# Удаление всех папок кроме одной

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть `task` который перед сборкой очищает папку

```
gulp.task('clear', function () {
    return del.sync('MyPage');
});
```

Как сделать чтобы он удалял все папки кроме одной, например `img`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так работает:

```
['!dist/.git','dist/**/*']
```

`'dist/**/*'` - здесь удаляются файлы в папке, 
а если `'dist/**'`, то удаляется вся папка dist и `'!dist/.git'` не спасает.

В конкретно этом случае, у меня не трогает .git, если прописать только `'dist/**/*'`

del по умолчанию не удаляет папки, у которых название начинается с точки

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var del = require('del');

 gulp.task('clear', function () {
    del.sync(['path/**', '!path/yourFolder']);
 });
```

`yourFolder` - название твоей папки, `path` - путь.

Comment: Все равно удаляет

Comment: @MegaRoks верный путь указал (`./**`, `!./img`)? Предыдущий `task` удалил?

Comment: да все правильно указал, но он все равно удалил папку `del.sync(['MyPage/**', '!MyPage/.git']);`

Comment: @MegaRoks ты не хочешь удалять `.git` файл в папке?

Comment: Да, я не хочу удалять `.git` файл в папке